# Redirect to a particular tab

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

```
<ul class="tabs" style="background: ">  

                    <li><a href="javascript:tabSwitch('tab_1', 'content_1');" id="tab_1" class="active">Payment Gateway Basics</a></li>  

                    <li><a href="javascript:tabSwitch('tab_4', 'content_4');" id="tab_4" >Contact Us</a></li>

                </ul>
```

These are my tabs, once I submit a form in the "contact us" tab, it goes back to the first tab. Can anyone tell me how to stay in the same tab?
I'm using PHP server side switching, I'm using JavaScript.

(I used `href` not `onclick` in the listing. Stack Overflow doesn't allow to use more `href` so I changed it into `onclick`, before this post was edited).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no directly provision

You have to pass some querystring

Read it on page_load in javascript

and set the tab from javascript based on the query string value.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some initialization script to determine what tab to activate when loading your page. The most common way is to add an anchor to your request url and read that using javascript. Evaluate that value to determine what tab to activate and do so with your javascript tabSwitch function.

This is a very simplistic example but illustrates the idea. This should be executed after [domready](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-domready).

```
var activeTab = self.document.location.hash;
if(activeTab !== ''){
    switchTab(activeTab);
}
```